# Generics parameter, Item or Node?

Tags: java, generics, iterator

I have some doubt on the generics parameter type in the [Stack](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Stack.java.html)

```
public class Stack<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
private int N;                // size of the stack
private Node<Item> first;     // top of stack

// helper linked list class
private static class Node<Item> {
    private Item item;
    private Node<Item> next;
}
 ....
```

Why Generics parameter type being {Item} instead {Node} here? after all, it is the **Node** we are iterating on.

Comment: did you check `private static class Node<Item>` in the link you provided?

Comment: any. thing in that makes a difference？

Answer (score 2):

No, a `Node` is simply an implementation detail. Note how it's a `private` class. You wouldn't be able to access it outside `Stack`.

Say you have a `Stack` of books. You're going to iterate over the books, not over the nodes holding those books. That would break encapsulation.